# Split string at last specified occurence of "special" sign + C

Tags: c, string, split

I have a string (pathname) in C, and I need to remove the last /... from the string.

> Ex: home/usr/bin/ls
>
> Wanted result: home/usr/bin

I can't seem to think of a way to do this to be honest. I tried strtok() but this splits the string from the first occurence of the delimiter, I just need to remove the text after the last occurence of "/". If anyone has any pointers to a method in C that can help me to this, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strrchr`.

Here max string length is 50 bytes.

```
int main()
{
    char s1[50];
    printf("enter your string\n");
    fgets(s1, 50, stdin);
    char *p;
    p=strrchr(s1, '/');
    if(p)
        *p='\0';
    printf("output is %s\n",s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to `memset` before `fgets` 2) You don't check if `p` is NULL

Comment: Thanks @Alter Mann for pointing out here....but I'm removing last one...used strrchr

Comment: Yes, excuse me, `strrchr` find the last ocurrence, +1 because I didn't now this function was part of the standard

Comment: Worked like a charm! Still wondering how people know of all these smart functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Loop strtok until no more / are found, then split at previously found /

Or, in this special case try using the dirname() function

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways to do this. One of the simplest is to use `strrchr` to find last occurrence of `'/'` in the path and set it to `null` (i.e. make it the new `end of string`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    char mypath[] = "home/usr/bin/ls";

    char *p = strrchr (mypath, '/');            /* find last '/' in mypath */

    *p = 0;                                     /* set as null-termination */

    printf ("\n mypath : %s\n\n", mypath);      /* print it */

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/trimpath

mypath : home/usr/bin
```

Another alternative is to find the length of `mypath` (i.e. `size_t len = strlen (mypath);`) and then using a pointer, decrement the pointer `mypath + len -1` until `/` is found and set `/` to `null`:

```
char *p = (mypath + strlen (mypath) - 1);
while (p > mypath)
{
    if (*p == '/') {
        *p = 0;
        break;
    }
    p--;
}
```